# смена цвета навигации при загрузке другой страницы

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

навигация имеет position absolute, есть страницы где бг темный, там навигация должна быть белой и наоборт, переорпеделить классы не получается, как это можно реализовать, буду благодарен
index.php:

```
<?php 
include "includes/nav.php";
 ?>
<?php 
    if (isset ($_GET['page'])) {

        $page = $_GET["page"];
        $filename = "includes/" . $page . '.php';

        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include $filename;
        }else{
            include 'includes/home.php';
        }

    }else{
        include 'includes/home.php';
    }
 ?>
<?php 
include "includes/footer.php";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть страницы где бг темный, там навигация должна быть белой и наоборт, переорпеделить классы не получается, как это можно реализовать,

Класс в примере `main`, у вас будет другой возможно `nav`. Проверяется наличие класса `dark`, меняет его на светлый и наоборот.

```js
// Код следует поместить в шапку сайта
var main = document.querySelector('.main');

if (main.classList.contains('dark')) {

  console.log('Change NAV color to light');
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // dark to light
  main.classList.remove('dark');
  main.classList.add('light')
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

} else {
  console.log('Change NAV color to dark');
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  // light to dark
  main.classList.remove('light')
  main.classList.add('dark')
  //----------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

```css
/******************** Стили меняющие NAV ********************/
.dark {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}

.light {
  background: #FFF4AA;
}
/********************  ********************/
```

```html
<div class="main dark">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium esse rem ducimus ea ex veniam in officiis possimus. Maxime inventore eveniet est assumenda iusto labore veniam quod amet? Quam, aut!
</div>
```